# ImageJ image stack shifted

Tags: imagej

I have taken images of cells using confocal microscope. When the file size is large, the image stack starts to shift downwards at a later stage. The shifted image just repeats the earlier images. The image stack is fine when i open it with a compatible software (Zen) but i need imageJ to do some editing. The original file is in .lsm format and is around 6GB. Here's a link to my video showing the shifted stack when i open the file in imageJ. Any help would be great. https://1drv.ms/v/s!AnUarFrjoIltl1jZya_GstBiCghC

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to use a registration function. Maybe this plugin (http://imagej.net/Name_Landmarks_and_Register) would be the best option, since it would allow you to choose a cell or two that you feel confidently able to identify, and register (line up) the images using those cells as landmarks.